# how can I show the output in the component instead of console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a quick app.js file in react which shows me if the number is prime or not every 1s to infinity through the console.log , rn I wanna make it to render in the browser itself " in the home page of mine I mean " instead of console.log , any ideas?

````
import {useInterval} from "../hooks/use-interval";
let num = 0
export default function Task1Prime() {
    const isPrime = num => {
        for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if(num % i === 0) return num+" isnt prime number";
        return num+ " is prime number";
    }
    useInterval(function (){
        console.log(isPrime(num++));

    },1000)
    return (
        <div className="task">
        </div>
    );
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import {useInterval} from "../hooks/use-interval";
import {useState} from "react";
let num = 0
export default function Task1Prime() {

    const isPrime = num => {
        for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if(num % i === 0) return num+" isnt prime number";
        return num+ " is prime number";
    }
    const [isNumPrime, setIsNumPrime] = useState(isPrime(num))
    useInterval(function (){
        setIsNumPrime(isPrime(num++));

    },1000)
    return (
        <div className="task">
            { isNumPrime }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Use a state variable isNumPrime and just update it with the function and it'll automatically change the element on the page.